# Mysql++ simple script compilation failure

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql++

I started learning c++ just a while ago, and I'm currently trying to create a simple mysql db connection. Although I have a web developer background setting up everything was pretty hard because of no c++ knowledge and how things work. Anyway I managed to install mysql++ and I got a piece of code from a tutorial that looks like this:

```
#include </usr/local/include/mysql++/mysql++.h>
#include </usr/local/include/mysql++/cmdline.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char* db      = "backseat";
    const char* server  = "localhost";
    const char* user    = "root";
    const char* pass    = "root";

    mysqlpp::Connection conn(true);

    if ( conn.connection(db, server, user, pass) ) 
    {
        mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query('SHOW TABLES');
        if ( mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult res = query.store() )
        {
            cout << "We have: " << endl;
            for (size_t i=0; i < res.num_rows(); i++)
            {
                cout << '\t' << res[i][0] << endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cerr << "Failed to get item list: " << query.error() << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "DB connection failed: " << conn.error() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

which is supposed to work but g++ gives me the following output:

```
syd@whitebook:~/Desktop$ g++ sql.cpp -o sql -DMYSQLPP_MYSQL_HEADERS_BURIED
sql.cpp:19:37: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
sql.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
sql.cpp:17:12: error: ‘class mysqlpp::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
sql.cpp:19:50: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/local/include/mysql++/connection.h:251:8: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘mysqlpp::Query mysqlpp::Connection::query(const char*)’ [-fpermissive]
syd@whitebook:~/Desktop$
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also would you suggest mysql++ or something else?

PS: tutorial - guide taken from here: http://my-problem-solved.blogspot.gr/2010/12/installing-mysql-server-and-mysql-apl.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo (t missing)

```
mysqlpp::Connecion conn(true);
```

should be

```
mysqlpp::Connection conn(true);
               ^
               ^
```

You may have other errors when you correct this but this is the cause of your compilation errors. If you read the compilation error message **very** carefully you can see that it actually echos back the mistyped class name `Connecion`.

**In light of your rewriting the question**, I believe the function you want is called

```
 conn.connect(db, server, user, pass)
```

This certainly works for me when I use mysql++. You can also use

```
conn.connected();
```

to see if your connection is OK;

Also

```
mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query("SHOW TABLES");
```

instead of

```
mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query('SHOW TABLES');
```

Or you can use the `<<` operator

```
Query query = conn.query();
query << "SHOW TABLES";
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo I updated my question. The typo was not the case.